# C++ Build Windows build fatal error LNK1104 gmock.lib

Tags: aeron

I'm trying to build [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/Aeron) on Windows with VS2022. I have all requirements stated in README.md (eg I've installed JDK etc) and have run the build script in Developer PowerShell VS2022 using the following script

```
$ mkdir -p cppbuild/Debug
$ cd cppbuild/Debug
$ cmake ../..
$ cmake --build . --clean-first
$ ctest
```

However, I'm getting lots of errors during build `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file`, such as the following:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\..\thirdparty\gmock\src\gmock-build\lib\Debug\gmock.lib' [C:\Use
rs\o\Desktop\IPCTesting\aeron-master\cppbuild\Debug\aeron-client\src\test\c\symbol_table_test.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/o/Desktop/IPCTesting/aeron-master/aeron-client/src/test/cpp_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt
  SystemTest.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\..\thirdparty\gmock\src\gmock-build\lib\Debug\gmock.lib' [C:\Use
rs\o\Desktop\IPCTesting\aeron-master\cppbuild\Debug\aeron-client\src\test\cpp_wrapper\systemTest.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/o/Desktop/IPCTesting/aeron-master/aeron-client/src/test/cpp_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt
  SystemTest.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\..\..\thirdparty\gmock\src\gmock-build\lib\Debug\gmock.lib' [C:\Use
rs\o\Desktop\IPCTesting\aeron-master\cppbuild\Debug\aeron-client\src\test\cpp_wrapper\systemTestW.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/o/Desktop/IPCTesting/aeron-master/aeron-client/src/test/cpp/CMakeLists.txt
  TermAppenderTest.cpp

....
```

But it looks like the googlemock project has been absorbed into the GoogleTest project (assuming gmock.lib is googlemock?).

Can anyone advise how to build Aeron for C++ on Windows?

Edit: Ps I know there is an included auto build script but trying to build from github project.

Comment: Can not open a library file usually means one or more of the following: 1. your path or file name is wrong, 2. you are mixing 32 and 64 bit or 3. the file is corrupt. I expect the problem is #2

Comment: I don't think there's much I can do about that as it's meant to be an automated CMake build script. I did notice the cppbuild directory does contain googletest-release-1.11.0.zip which includes googlemock so it does look like one of the issues you mention.

Comment: See if the library exists. Also you may want to try building from a shorter path. Years ago I have had problems building some CMake based opensource software when the path length was long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command from the Aeron base directory to simplify the build:

`$ cppbuild\cppbuild`

Comment: That's the automated cppbuild.cmd file, that does work. I was trying to do it manually from the instructions. It seems like folder `thirdparty` gets built into directory `RelWithDebInfo` rather than `Debug`, is that my fault or the scripts? Ps I watched one of your talks last night which is why I'm trying this. Thank you.

Comment: It is likely that those instructions are out of date (the `cppbuild` script is the way to go).

Comment: I've updated the instructions on the readme.  It was missing the setting of the build type during the initial run of CMake.